# Possibly converting JSONObject to java string

Tags: json, string, processing

[TO CLARIFY I'M WORKING IN PROCESSING]

All of the questions I can see are about doing this the other way round. I have variable which is a string taken from a weather API, and I want to test and see if it is a certain word (i.e. "Rain" or "Clouds"). I have the framework for this code set up but it doesn't appear to like the part where I check what is explained above. I figured this might be because I'm trying to compare a JSONObject with a normal java string, but of all the places I've looked I have't gotten a straight answer on how to convert it. Can anybody help me here?

I'm not too brilliant at coding so sorry if I'm a bit slow.

here is where the JSONObject is made

```
JSONArray cityWeatherObject = city.getJSONArray("weather");
  JSONObject weather = cityWeatherObject.getJSONObject(0);
  cityDesc = weather.getString("main");
```

here is where I'm trying to compare it to a string

```
void drawWeather() {
  println(cityDesc, "Clouds");
  if (cityDesc == "Rain") {
    for (int i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++) {
      rainDrops[i].wind = cityWind;
      rainDrops[i].fall();
      rainDrops[i].spawn();
    }
  }
  if (cityDesc == "Clouds") {
    println("Clouds selected");
    for (int i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++) {
      clouds[i].wind = cityWind;
      clouds[i].drift();
      clouds[i].spawn();
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the equals() method, as in if (a.equals(b)), instead of if (a == b). A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the equals() method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The troubleshooting reference has a longer explanation.)

Source: [here](https://processing.org/reference/String.html)